# python cant find module in sys.path

Tags: python, sys.path

I use the following command to install modules in home/.local since I dont have admin rights

`pip install --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/.local" package_name`

it is installed in my home dir and other cant run my script, so I move them to python lib/site-packages directory where others have access to. Then I add `sys.path.insert(0, path_to_lib)` in my script to import that module. This is how I install and use modules in my script and it always works fine. But when I did the same for a module "marrow.mailer", my script shows `No module named marrow.mailer` not sure why, the lib/site-packages folder does have that module. Please help me in finding solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the issue in using pip install <packagename> --user or creating virtual environment and installing without root permissions

Comment: Tried --user, it keeps failing with "Failed building wheel for module ". Havent use virtual environment before. But this method has always worked for me, but not for this module.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the whl file and installing it locally? `wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/4f/b4174aa6754cd7cf610b4f85e47de61bb4f3c2fe8bb0aa5e96e058089b9f/marrow.mailer-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Sure, will try that. Is there a reason on why python is not able to find the module even though it is in sys.path? @Yash Kumar Atri