# cant find moduals even though sys.path searches in right place

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, sys.path

I am working on widows10 with python3.7

I have downloaded opencv and numpy and sklearn(scikit-learn) and they are in C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages (where pip put them) and when I run

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I get the output:

`['', 'C:\\Python35\\Lib', 'C:\\Python35\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\E6440', 'C:\\Python37\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python37\\lib', 'C:\\Python37', 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']`

on cmd it says *C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages* which is one of the paths it looks in for when importing but then as soon as I run some code it gives a *no module named ___* error

this is similar to the question [python cant find module in sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027943/python-cant-find-module-in-sys-path) but the comments in that one did not help me

*edit*

solved by using PYTHONPATH that was accurate to the python version

Comment: Can an installation of Python35 be a source of the problems?

Comment: python 3.5 is not on the laptop, I installed about a week ago

Comment: So delete them from you PATH, you will get a cleaner system. You can also dig into environments, eg using pipenv

Comment: well, I just looked at the PYTHONPATH variable and, like a noob I am, it had all the paths as 35 (just saw the output I put in the question) and say they where saying python35 *face palm* this is why you dont copy past from a website without reading what it is your pasting thanks

Comment: all those things usually work well and unnoticed, but once ina  while you get to look into internals. glad you hard it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you're trying to import the module from may be available in the Python 3.5 installation too, but the package for Python 3.5 may be missing the module you're trying to import. Try moving the Python 3.7 paths ahead of the Python 3.5 paths in your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: what fixed the problem was by putting my code in the folder: site-packages where the modules were. but that is not ideal for the long term